# CSRF Token issue in Django app deployed in Railway, "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Tags: django, django-csrf, csrf-token, railway

The error I get is "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGKrz.png)

The site works fine and there are no issues on localhost

I tried adding this base domain in my settings.py but I am still getting the same error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQTP.png)

I also tried this fix, and reloaded the requirements.txt but to no avail:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azgBN.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also please make sure that you try to paste the code in your question as code and not image. 
Take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the trusted origins like this (if you are using Django 4.0 or above)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS must include scheme and host, for Django 4.0 and above. If you are using Django 3.2 and below, this is not required

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://web-production-716d.up.railway.app']
```

Comment: This worked as I was using Django 4.0 or above. Thank you! Noted on the pasting code and not images.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having similar issue, when deploying Django application on Railway.

```
# not working for me 
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://web-production-716d.up.railway.app'] 

# worked for me
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.railway.app']
```

Thanks